# Graph API, list last posts incl total likes of posts

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to make a custom-feed from my companies Facebook page to our website. I query the Graph API of Facebook to get this information.

Facebook changed the API a while ago to not include like counts in the normal page query. In the documentation it says to add summary=1 to get the total likes. My query does not return the total_count tho when I query it.

I am omitting my acces_token in the queries because I'm using the API Explorer.

Query I use to get posts:

```
Raafh/posts?limit=4
```

trying to add summary=1 does nothing with the query.

I can however do another query which will return the likes and the total count, but not the post info so I can't use it, or I have to use two queries.

```
Raafh/posts?fields=likes.summary(1).limit(1)
```

This posts the last like + the total_count.

How can I combine these two in one query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add required fields in comma separated format to get post data like shown in example below.

```
Raafh/posts?fields=likes.summary(1).limit(1),id,message,from,picture,link,name,caption,description
```

Comment: You are my hero! I was fooling around with a FQL already, which btw are pretty awesome too.

Comment: How could I also pull a bigger version of the picture used in the post?

Comment: If I'm not wrong this is an external image. So I'm not sure if you can get it from facebook.

Comment: you are correct, some are posted tho and have a bigger version. I might need to to a new graph query to get those in an if(statement)

Comment: Well in that case you have to play smart. just replcae **"_s"** to **"_n"** from file name("1463639_676056882424942_1939116814_s.jpg") and you are done :)

Comment: yeah I was thinking that! just need to check the type of post. Can I filter cover-updates in Graph API or should I really switch to FQL then?

Comment: I think Graph API would be enough. FQL is bit tricky and have limitation with joins. so IF Graph API would solve your purpose; its better to use it.